# How can I have a Django signal call a model method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Maybe it's just late, but I cannot figure out why this isn't working.  When I have a post_save signal call a generic function, it works, but when I have a post_save signal call a method from a model, nothing happens.  Here is code that works:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    # Model junk...

def send_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print "DO STUFF"

signals.post_save.connect(send_email, sender=Revision)
```

But this does not work:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    # Model junk...

    def send_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            print "DO STUFF"

signals.post_save.connect(Revision.send_email, sender=Revision)
```

Is there a kind soul out there who will keep me from smashing my head into the wall?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe helpful? [Django pre_save signal does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6153730/143804)

Comment: The best practice is to put all your signals in a `signals.py`; don't intermingle them with the django model class.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem in the second one is you are using an unbounded method `send_mail`. If you really want to call `send_mail` from within a class, maybe [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) or [`@staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) will help you out:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    # Model junk...

    @classmethod
    def send_email(cls, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            print "DO STUFF"

signals.post_save.connect(Revision.send_email, sender=Revision)
```

or

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    # Model junk...

    @staticmethod
    def send_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            print "DO STUFF"

signals.post_save.connect(Revision.send_email, sender=Revision)
```

Alternatively without using these decorators, you can pass the bounded instance method:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
# Model junk...

    def send_email(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            print "DO STUFF"

signals.post_save.connect(Revision().send_email, sender=Revision)
```

---

References:

1. From the Django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L37):

   ```
   def connect(self, receiver, sender=None, weak=True, dispatch_uid=None):
       """
       Connect receiver to sender for signal.

       Arguments:

           receiver
               A function or an instance method which is to receive signals.
               Receivers must be hashable objects.

               If weak is True, then receiver must be weak-referencable (more
               precisely saferef.safeRef() must be able to create a reference
               to the receiver).

               Receivers must be able to accept keyword arguments.

               If receivers have a dispatch_uid attribute, the receiver will
               not be added if another receiver already exists with that
               dispatch_uid.
   ```
2. Difference between `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`: [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: Your third example using the instance method, the instance being called here is a new one, right, not the instance that was —here— saved? Edit: Oh but the `instance` variable *is* the one being saved. Seems a bit silly to do it like that, but I see that you're just showing you *can* do that if you need to. Cool.

Comment: And how do you do that with `receiver` decorator?

Comment: I don't think that third example works. From my testing, instance methods are not the same across all instances