# How to count how many times foreignkey object can be used

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models.py

```
class Timing(models.Model):
    time = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0) # max=20

class Ticket(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    no = models.ForeignKey(Timing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is there a way I can increment the value of `count` variable in class `Timing` by `1` whenever I use `no` variable to connect object of `Timing` class (whenever I use the `ForeignKey` variable)?

Comment: When you said *use* do you mean to *call* the variable or you mean something like save the model etc. ?

Comment: Yes....exactly.

Comment: Alright I am pretty sure that you can do that with a custom signal. Checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549977/how-can-i-have-a-django-signal-call-a-model-method

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar. I'll look into it.